# Firebase Auth Is Giving Me An Error When Trying To Resolve A Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, runtime-error

I need help with this Google Auth Function… I have a method doCreateUserWithEmail and password in firebase.js (React) that looks like this.

```
doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
 this.auth
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));};
```

When I take then .then and below and and attach it to signUp.js like so…

```
onSubmitHandler = event => {
event.preventDefault();
const { email, passwordOne } = this.state;
this.props.firebase.doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
this.props.history.push(ROUTES.HOME);
```

};

I get this error..

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
SignUpFormBase._this.onSubmitHandler
src/components/signUp/signUp.js:31
 28 | onSubmitHandler = event => {
 29 |   event.preventDefault();
 30 |   const { email, passwordOne } = this.state;
 > 31 |   this.props.firebase.doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
 passwordOne)
 | ^  32 |     .then(response => console.log(response))
 33 |     .catch(err => console.log(err));
 34 |   this.props.history.push(ROUTES.HOME);
 View compiled
```

and yes, I deleted it off of doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword when I get the error..
but the function does register the user in Firebase successfully, and if I take away the .then and .catch it works fine.

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't returning anything from `doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword` so it returns `undefined` and calling `.then()` on `undefined` causes the error you are seeing.

Just return the `Promise` from `doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword` and that should fix it:

```
doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
  return this.auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```